# Why am I getting the Command Failed due to signal: Segmentation Fault: 11 error

Tags: ios, json, api, datastore

I am getting a "Command failed due to signal: Segmentation Fault: 11" Error and I cannot understand why, also my code periodically turns white. 
Here is my code. In my project I am calling an API, which is working just fine and I am passing that json information over to a database and a view controller will then use that information from the datastore to populate a collection view.

```
import Foundation

class MovieDataBase
{
    static let sharedInstance = MovieDataBase()
    private init() {}
    //creating a singleton for the MovieDataStore

    var movies = [Movie]()
    //array to store all the movie objects from the json

    let movieSearchTerms = ["love", "fantasy", "romance", "mystery", "thriller", "musical", "family", "horror", "sci-fi"]

    func getMoviesWithCompletion(completion: () -> ()) {

        let randomNum = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(movieSearchTerms.count))

        OMDBAPIClient.getMovieResultsFromSearch(self.movieSearchTerms[Int(randomNum)]) { (arrayOfMovies) in
            for singleMovie in arrayOfMovies
            {

                let neededTitle = singleMovie["title"] as? String
                let neededYear = singleMovie["year"] as? String
                let neededImbdID = singleMovie["imdbID"] as? String
                let neededType = singleMovie["type"] as? String
                let neededPosterURL = singleMovie["posterURL"] as? String

                guard let
                    unwrappedTitle = neededTitle,
                    unwrappedYear = neededType,
                    unwrappedImbdID = neededImbdID,
                    unwrappedType = neededType,
                    unwrappedPosterURL = neededPosterURL

                    else { print("AN ERROR OCCURRED HERE"); return }

                var movie = Movie.init(title: unwrappedTitle, year: singleMovie["year"], imdbID: singleMovie["imbdID"], type: singleMovie["type"], posterURL: singleMovie["posterURL"])

                movies.append(movie)
            }
            completion()
        }

}


}
```

Comment: Can you add the error screenshot and in which row it occurs?

Comment: In my experience, this has always been a bug with the Swift compiler. Can you post an screenshot of the whole error?

Comment: I'm also curious of why you are doing `Movie.init`. You should just use the constructor syntax (`Movie(title: ...`)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it wasn't working was because I had the wrong spelling of the information that I needed from the JSON hence it was throwing all sorts of errors. Next time it would be wise to look at the JSON information in postman and make sure the code that you write matches the information that you need from the JSON, else you will run into all sorts of errors.